# How model nested activities in an Activity Diagram in Papyrus

Tags: android-activity, port, diagram, papyrus, sysml

I am trying to create nested activity diagrams in Papyrus.

My Problem: I don't know how to create a sub-activity-diagram directly from an action of my main activity-diagram. I want also to transfer ports from the action to the sub-diagram. In cameo it works easily as described in MagicGrid Handbook:
[create sub-activity-diagram from an action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5SR.png)
[sub-activity diagram including ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgxXe.png)

In Papyrus I can only create a sub-diagram manually and then create a hyperlink to the main diagram. But ports are not transferred in this case.

Any idea? Thanks and BR, Lennox

Comment: I guess you mean pins. They share the shape with ports, but are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean pins. do you have any idea how to solve the problem I explained above?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience working with papyrus.

Comment: Did you try connecting an object flow directly to the ports already?

Comment: @lennox84 by the way, thanks for the pointer to the MagicGrid Book of Knowledge. I had no idea it existed! https://discover.3ds.com/magicgrid-book-of-knowledge